# Serial port : converting data

Tags: c#, gps, serial-port

i have only recently started to code in c#. I took on the challenge to develop a GPS program at work.
 We have the data that is supplied by a serial port. The representation on screen is allready coded and ready to use.
 I just need to get the data from the serial port and put it in a database.
 The information i have are the settings for the port (Baudrate 9600, 8, parity.odd, 1).
 They also gave me the structure of the syntax (  ), its transmitted as a stream of bytes.
 The final thing i have is a screenshot of how the data looks like when its correctly received.
 http://i61.tinypic.com/2ajcpww.png

As far as the code goes, the database part is not a problem at all. Once i have the correct data from the serial port i will be able to load it in de database and then its available for the presentation software.

Would anyone with experience be able to guide me on my way. Is there any more information i need to find out from the company who suplied the data system.

The code i have to read from the serial port is this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ClarityListener
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private SerialPort comPort = new SerialPort();
        string RxString;
        string port = "COM1";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            comPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(comPort_DataReceived);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void comPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            int count = comPort.BytesToRead;
            byte[] data = new byte[count];
            comPort.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
            RxString = (BitConverter.ToString(data));
            this.Invoke(new EventHandler(DisplayText));
        }


        private void DisplayText(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText(RxString);
        }


        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (comPort.IsOpen)
            {
                comPort.Close();
            }
            else if (!comPort.IsOpen)
            {

                try
                {
                    comPort.PortName = port;
                    comPort.BaudRate = 9600;
                    comPort.Parity = Parity.Odd;
                    comPort.DataBits = 8;
                    comPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
                    comPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
                    comPort.Open();
                }
                catch (Exception er)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(er.Message);
                }
            }
            if (comPort.IsOpen)
            {
                richTextBox1.Clear();

            }
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (comPort.IsOpen)
            {
                comPort.Close();
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Poort is gesloten");

            this.Dispose();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (comPort.IsOpen)
            {
                comPort.Close();
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Poort is gesloten");

            this.Close();
            this.Dispose();
        }


    }
}
```

The final outcome should be readable by humans (database).
The data that is transmitted is like 6005 1 500 1058 1609 0116 51°08'924 02°43'252.

This i what my program atm reads from the stream:

```
02-71-00-00-0C-84-07-1317-11-05-23-00-76-26-8522-8C-00-00-27-FB-00-01A3-BF-0302-72-00-00-0C-85-    07-0C17-12-05-24-00-70-25-E021-3C-00-00-23-E9-00-019D-AF-0302-73-00-00-0C-8C-07-0E17-12-05-19-00-    76-25-541F-D8-00-00-17-E1-00-018F-BC-0302-74-00-00-0C-8F-07-0D17-12-05-2D-00-76-26-A823-70-00-00-    33-D0-00-01B0-AE-0302-75-00-00-0E-B4-04-C517-51-04-B6-00-70-26-0121-7B-00-00-06-7D-00-0180-5F-    0302-76-00-00-0E-B8-00-0000-00-00-00-00-00-00-0000-00-00-00-00-00-00-0111-2F-0302-77-00-00-0F-8C-    09-1013-94-05-1B-00-7D-25-3C35-0E-00-00-30-14-00-02BE-9F-0302-78-00
```

Comment: Having done similar things before I know there is ton of C# code out there for doing this. I would suggest looking around before doing a lot of work to develop your own.

Comment: Unfortunately, unless you have directions from the vendor, you probably won't know if the technical side is right until you convert the raw data into actual coordinates.  Even if I could see a pattern in the data you present, I'd be very worried about saying so, since it could be a coincidence that would lead you astray.  The code looks fine, though, assuming you can guarantee the device will always be on COM1.

Comment: The device is always on COM1. I have just send a request mail to the support of the supplier of the system. Just to see if they can give me some more information. Because its an old system, works in combination with a broadcasting system for public transportation. The software is to be used to track vehicles on a railroad, so i can't rely on most of the "standard" software.

Comment: Maybe it would be more obvious if you didn't convert it to hex.

Comment: I didn't think COM1 was a mistake, but figured I should mention it on the off chance.  But yes, hopefully the vendor can just tell you what to look for.  Otherwise, you'll need to look for hex values that "look like" they "might be" coordinates and patch the code every time an unexpected case comes up.  Doable, but a huge waste if it can be headed off.

Answer (score 0):

I converted the hex output and it looks like complete nonsense. This is often caused if you are using an incorrect Baud Rate. It is also unusual to see an Odd parity (most are none or even). Please check the COM setting with the Vendor as this is most likely the cause.

I work with serial ports most days (I work for a hardware vendor myself) and can't see anything obviously wrong with your code. The only difference to what I typically do is that I personally like to use the Encoding.Default.GetString() method to convert from a byte[] to a string.

I hope this helps.